# Ad isn't loading

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, ads

I followed the google tutorial on interstitial ads, but whenever I try to display my ad it never is loaded.  I've tried to use AdListener instead of interstitial.isLoaded, but still the same result.  I've also given the ad over 2 minutes to load a couple times, so something must be wrong.

I am using an AVD, could that be the problem?  It can connect to the Internet just fine when I use the browser though.

*removed an incorrect link*

androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidLauncher"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AndroidLauncher

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.GameEventListener;
import com.JrodManU.LaserJumper.LaserJumper;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameEventListener {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    boolean showed = false;
    boolean loaded = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new LaserJumper(this), config);

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("******");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        //.addTestDevice(testDeviceId)
        .build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            public void onAdLoaded(){
               loaded = true;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean displayInterstitial() {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(loaded) {
                    interstitial.show();
                    showed = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("failed"); //Always prints failed
                    showed = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return showed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already create the interstitial Ad unit in the google Admob dashboard?

Comment: Also check the logcat output (filter for `tag:Ads`). Admob is logging when the ad finished loading & it also logs for the case something went wrong.

Comment: "could not find com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity, please make sure it is declared in AndroidManifest.xml" Guess I didn't do the xml right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got this error:

> could not find com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity, please make sure
>   it is declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Then adding this activity declaration within the `<application>` tag in your Manifest should fix it:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!  After two weeks I finally have ads :)